# js mongoDb copy item gives external data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array:

```
"data": [
        {
            "photo": "no-photo.jpg",
            "_id": "5e9aabd9c975a10a7ee48476",
            "title": "Title",
            "description": "Description",
            "phone": "77477926783",
            "fromLocation": "5e9aa8a9c975a10a7ee48474",
            "toLocation": "5e9aa8bac975a10a7ee48475",
            "price": 1000000,
            "date": "1998-02-23T00:00:00.000Z",
            "user": "5e91729f147813258ef1f373",
            "createdAt": "2020-04-18T07:27:21.743Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "courses": [],
            "id": "5e9aabd9c975a10a7ee48476"
        }
    ]
```

and I use `for...loop`:

```
for (const item of res.advancedResults.data) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

it gives normal:

```
{
 "photo": "no-photo.jpg",
 "_id": "5e9aabd9c975a10a7ee48476",
 "title": "Title",
 "description": "Description",
 "phone": "77477926783",
 "fromLocation": "5e9aa8a9c975a10a7ee48474",
 "toLocation": "5e9aa8bac975a10a7ee48475",
 "price": 1000000,
 "date": "1998-02-23T00:00:00.000Z",
 "user": "5e91729f147813258ef1f373",
 "createdAt": "2020-04-18T07:27:21.743Z",
 "__v": 0,
 "courses": [],
 "id": "5e9aabd9c975a10a7ee48476"
}
```

But when I copy it like:

```
for (const item of res.advancedResults.data) {
  console.log({...item})
}
```

It gives:

```
{ '$__':
     InternalCache {
       strictMode: true,
       selected: {},
       shardval: undefined,
       saveError: undefined,
       validationError: undefined,
       adhocPaths: undefined,
       removing: undefined,
       inserting: undefined,
       saving: undefined,
       version: undefined,
       getters: {},
       _id: 5e9aabd9c975a10a7ee48476,
       populate: undefined,
       populated: undefined,
       wasPopulated: false,
       scope: undefined,
       activePaths: [StateMachine],
       pathsToScopes: {},
       cachedRequired: {},
       session: null,
       '$setCalled': Set {},
       ownerDocument: undefined,
       fullPath: undefined,
       emitter: [EventEmitter],
       '$options': [Object] },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc:
     { photo: 'no-photo.jpg',
       _id: 5e9aabd9c975a10a7ee48476,
       title: 'Title',
       description: 'Description',
       phone: '77477926783',
       fromLocation: 5e9aa8a9c975a10a7ee48474,
       toLocation: 5e9aa8bac975a10a7ee48475,
       price: 1000000,
       date: 1998-02-23T00:00:00.000Z,
       user: 5e91729f147813258ef1f373,
       createdAt: 2020-04-18T07:27:21.743Z,
       __v: 0 },
    '$locals': {},
    '$$populatedVirtuals': { courses: [] },
    '$init': true }
```

How can I correctly copy object?

Comment: because you are getting the mongoose model, Change to `console.log({...item.toObject()})` to get your expected behavior

Comment: @KunalMukherjee can u copy your answer and past on answers) I will approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you perform any operation like `find`, `findOne`, .etc, Mongoose will wrap the result in Mongoose model / Document which will contain additional metadata.

As mentioned in the docs [`here`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and [`here`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) -

> [`Models`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model-js) are fancy constructors compiled from `Schema` definitions. An
>   instance of a model is called a [`document`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html). Models are responsible for
>   creating and reading documents from the underlying MongoDB database.
>
> Mongoose models provide several static helper functions for [CRUD
>   operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete). Each of these functions returns a [mongoose `Query` object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query).

---

From the looks of it, you are trying to get / destructure the mongoose model like a plain JavaScript object.

There are 2 ways to acheive this -

1. Using `{ lean: true }` option in your `model.find()` or
   `model.findOne()` methods or use the `lean()` method. However this
   contains some disadvantages which you can read
   [`here`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html).
2. Use the
   [`Document.prototype.toObject()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)
   method to converts the document into a plain javascript object.